# Outlook API returns 10 contacts

Tags: outlook

I have used https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0 endpoint to fetch contacts. I have done using Node.js. In odataParams I am passing $top = 4000. But still getting 10 contacts only. How can I avoid or disable pagination ?

Comment: Have you tried without `$top`? The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations#GetContacts) don't list it as a required parameter but it is used to control pagination.

Comment: @WaynePhipps I tried without $top as well but got 10 contacts only.

Comment: Check if the response includes an `odata.nextLink` property?

Comment: No. Response does not include odata.nextLink property.

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations#examples) suggests you can set `odata.maxpagesize`. Perhaps try setting that instead of `$top`. Another idea would be to get the `Count` and then read the users in batches

Comment: I was giving $top in different way. Now it's giving me 68 contacts instead of 75. I am setting $top = 75. How can I get all 75 contacts?